# New question for specific category or answer to main question with category tag

Tags: discussion, questions

I am a Fish shell user, but I usually search for *"How to do ... in bash?"* when I need to know how to do something as Fish hits are few and far between.

Answers do help, but I usually find I need to tweak things a bit (or quite a deal) to get it to work in Fish. When I am done and if I have figured things out, it seems like a good idea to post an answer in the original post with the Fish version, but that could appeal to downvotes since it's most likely not useful to non-Fish users.

The alternative is to create a new Fish-only question (and answer it myself).

Which one do you recommend?

Comment: A Fish-only question with the correct tag seems like a good idea to me.